# Admin area in my php website is vulnerable to sql injection without login

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

my website admin area is vulnerable to sql injection . I tried using havji and it hacked successfully to database. But how is this possible. without login it breaked into admin panel.
mysql_real_escape_string is not used in admin panel.AS its used by me only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge its because you are not using php exit; function

you might be using this

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');

}
 mysql and other php code here without filtering
```

but you must use

```
  session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: index');

        exit;
}
```

mysql and other php code here without filtering

Now any software or vulnerability scanner wont be able to check that you have loophole for sql injection. As exit function wont allow other code to be executed after itself. Still client side filtering is necessary.
You could also use die function too.

Comment: You should fix the SQL injection vulnerability nonetheless by consequently using mysql_real_escape_string or preferable parameterized queries. Otherwise this is a mine, just waiting for some code reuse in a couple of years. It is important to note that the above code does not completely prevent exploiting the vulnerability: [Cross site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) needs to be prevented, too.